# C++ declare a string literal in mutable memory

Tags: c++, string

I am working on a challenge given to me by a friend and to complete it I need to pass a mutable string into a function without prior declaration. (The function preforms some operations on the string so it must be mutable and due to constraints in the challenge I cannot declare the variable before the function call. Basically can

```
myFunction("abcdef");
```

be altered in such a way that the string is declared in the function call and passed or so that the passed string is not declared in non-mutable memory.

Comment: Just have your function take a `std::string`?  http://ideone.com/XFbKaZ

Comment: the function is designed to take a char array and does a lot of pointer manipulation so it would be easier if the argument remained a char pointer, could I declare a string and then convert it back to a char array?

Comment: I suppose `new char[]{"abcdef"}` would "work", but no, just no.

Comment: `myfunction(std::string("ABC").data());`

Comment: @KerrekSB: That's not mutable though, right?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Ah, right. So it should be `myfunction(&std::string("ABC")[0]);`, which should work because the `[]`-operator isn't lvalue qualified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a version which changes the call to be

```
myFunction("abcdef"_ncs);
```

I guess, this innocent addition for "non-const string" should be permissible. Here is the code:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

void myFunction(char* x) {
    std::cout << "x=" << x << "\n";
}

struct tmp_string {
    char* buffer;
    tmp_string(char const* str, std::size_t n)
        : buffer(std::strcpy(new char[n + 1], str)) {
    }
    tmp_string(tmp_string&& other): buffer(other.buffer) { other.buffer = 0; }
    ~tmp_string() { delete[] buffer; }
    operator char*() { return buffer; }
};

tmp_string operator"" _ncs(char const* str, std::size_t n) {
    return tmp_string(str, n);
}

int main()
{
    myFunction("abcdef"_ncs);
}
```

I didn't use `std::string` primarily because there is no neat conversion from a `std::string` to a non-`const` string. The only approach I could think of would be

```
myFunction(&std::string("abcdef")[0]);
```

At least, it would also neatly clean up after itself (as does the approach using `tmp_string` above). Note that starting with C++11 the approach taking the address of the first byte also yields a null-terminated string (for C++03 the string wasn't guaranteed to be null-terminated; since I had trouble verifying this guarantee: it is in 21.4.5 [string.access] paragraph 2).

Comment: What is in the world is `operator""`?

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: It is called the _literal-operator_ and is used to create user-defined literals. You can attach a suffix to integer, floating-point, or string literals which call this operator.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;   

void MyFunc(char* c)
{
    c[0] = 's'; 
    cout << c << endl;
    delete[] c;
}

int main()
{
   MyFunc(new char[3]{'a','b', 0});

   return 0;
}
```